# How can I do paging and sorting using spring data with Couchbase

Tags: java, sorting, spring-data, paging, couchbase

I am trying to do paging and sorting using `spring-data-couchbase` but it seems `org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository` has only `CouchbaseRepository` which is extending `CrudRepository<T,ID>`.

There is no interface extending from  `PagingAndSortingRepository<T,ID>`.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/1.0.x/api/org/springframework/data/couchbase/repository/CouchbaseRepository.html

I did implement an unconventional solution to the problem setting skip and limit. But want to get total number of page count, which is not available with this solution. 
It seems `Page<T>` does have `.getTotalPages()`

Comment: Please share your code

Answer (score 1):

Below are the steps to get the Pagination working.

1. update spring-data-couchbase version to `4.3.1` or above
2. Use `extends CouchbaseRepository<Object, Object>`
3. Build `Pagebale` Object.
4. `Page<Object> findAllById(String id, Pageable page)`

That's it

Answer (score 0):

there is currently no paging support with Spring Data Couchbase, you need to use the lower level API, which is basically the first version of Couchbase's Java SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Since Spring-Data-Couchbase 2.0.x support `PagingAndSortingRepository` to paging and sorting data.

The interface define:

```
public interface PagingAndSortingRepository<T, ID extends Serializable>
  extends CrudRepository<T, ID> {

  Iterable<T> findAll(Sort sort);

  Page<T> findAll(Pageable pageable);
}
```

Paging *Project* example:

```
public interface ProjectRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Project, String> {

    Page<Project> findByName(String name, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

4 Years on, sadly still no ReactiveCouchbasePagingAndSortingRepository.
Instead I will use indexes, and a combination of the offset parameter and the count select to solve this problem.
https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/aggregatefun.html#countn
https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/offset.html

```
@Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} where #{#n1ql.filter} ORDER BY name LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2;")
Flux<Location> findPage(int limit, int offset);
```

If they do add it, it should appear here (or in a later version)

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/4.0.x/api/index.html?org/springframework/data/couchbase/repository/package-tree.html