# How to query with Pageable with Spring Data and Couchbase

Tags: spring-data, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I just try to query with a PageRequest:

```
Page<MyEntity> entityPage = myRepository.findAll(new PageRequest(1, 20));
```

and this is my Repository

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends CouchbasePagingAndSortingRepository<MyEntity, String> {
}
```

But always get an empty Page object back.

I'm using 2.1.5.RELEASE for spring-data-couchbase. I read in this [older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30994744) that it wasn't implemented yet - but this was 2015 and in the [Spring Data for Couchbase documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.special-parameters) it's described in detail. So I guess it should work by now ...

Answer (score 0):

You are requesting for second page. Pages are zero indexed, thus providing 0 for page will return the first page.

Try this:

```
Page<MyEntity> entityPage = myRepository.findAll(new PageRequest(0, 20));
```